# error1833: cannot change colum id

Tags: mysql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm, alter-table

With prompt command, I have generated a database with doctine using **reverse engineering**. It worked perfectly:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:convert yml ./src/Gir/DatabaseBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

After, I create the **entities**:

```
php app/console doctrine:mapping:import GirDatabaseBundle annotation
```

And the **annotations**:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:entities GirDatabaseBundle
```

Then, I installed the new update of Symfony with `composer.phar`.

Then, the **FOSUserBundle** in order to manage users in my project.

I have to **update** my database with **doctrine** using this prompt command in order to generate the table users and the entities, etc:

```
php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

When I do this command, doctrine send me this **error** in the windows prompt command:

```
**[Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]**
An exception occured while executing 'ALTER TABLE agence CHANGE id id INT NOT NULL':
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change colum 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'fk_employe_agence1' of table 'gir.employe'

**[PDOException]**
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change colum 'id': used in a foreign key constraint 'fk_employe_agence1' of table 'gir.employe'
```

This the SQL of **agence** table:

```
--
-- Base de donnÃ©es :  `gir`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `agence`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `agence` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `nomVoie` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `numVoie` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `codePostal` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `comune` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `telephone` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `fax` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `entreprises_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`entreprises_id`),
  KEY `fk_agence_entreprises1_idx` (`entreprises_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

And this is the SQL of **employe** table:

```
--
-- Base de donnÃ©es :  `enexgir`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Structure de la table `employe`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `employe` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nom` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `prenom` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `poste` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `portable` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `ligneDirecte` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `faxDirect` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `etat` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `agence_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`agence_id`),
  KEY `fk_employe_agence1_idx` (`agence_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

--
-- Contraintes pour les tables exportÃ©es
--

--
-- Contraintes pour la table `employe`
--
ALTER TABLE `employe`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_employe_agence1` FOREIGN KEY (`agence_id`) REFERENCES `agence` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Someone should why and how to fix this with doctrine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the foreign keys is that Doctrine sometimes can't resolve them itself. But it usually works of you temporarily disable FKs. Try the following:

Prepare an SQL dump which will disable FK checks during import. Then tell Doctrine to dump the changes into a file, instead of applying them directly. Then import the file with MySQL.

```
# disable FK checks during the import
echo 'SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;' > dump.sql

# append the DB dump
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --complete >> dump.sql

# import the dump into MySQL
mysql -u username -p -D dbname < dump.sql
```

If that works without throwing errors, have Doctrine check if everything's consistent with the ORM definitions:

```
app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --complete
```

If this gives you any more SQL queries to execute, then do so. After that, you should be fine.

Comment: the import of the dump into MySql does not work, I have this `error:the operator "<" is reserved for a later use`

Comment: Uh, is it possible you're trying this on a Windows system? If so, is it correct that you are using forward slashes? (I honestly don't know, I thought that the backslash is the directory separator on Windows systems.)

Comment: Anyway, please try the following approach to pass the dump to MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2148816/3908235 (`Get-Content …`).

Comment: Yes I'm working on a windows system. I try like your link and I will tell you if it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This Solution is correct: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26628581/2400373

However if you work on Symfony 3, the correct is this:

```
bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql --complete >> dump.sql
```

Never used the instruction `php` before this instruction.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use this as a DataFixture here is how I've done it in the load method:

```
    $dumpFilePath  = "dump.sql";
    file_put_contents($dumpFilePath, "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; \n");

    $kernel = $this->container->get('kernel');
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);
    $options = array('command' => 'doctrine:schema:update', '--dump-sql' => true, '--complete' => true);

    $input = new ArrayInput($options);
    $output = new StreamOutput(fopen($dumpFilePath, 'a'));
    $application->run($input, $output);

    $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare(file_get_contents($dumpFilePath))->execute();
```