# ansible my sql module is not working in windows server

Tags: mysql, windows, ansible

I have my mysql installed on windows server 2012.When i am trying mysql module of ansible using following ansible playbook

```
- name: Execute mysql dump files
      #win_command: "mysql  -u{{ db_user }} -p  {{ db_database }} < {{ item.path }}"
      mysql_db:
        login_host: "{{ db_host }}"
        login_password: "{{ db_pass }}"
        login_user: "{{ db_user }}"
        login_port: "{{ db_port }}"
        name: "{{ db_database }}"
        state: import
        target: "{{ item.path }}"
      with_items:
          - "{{ files_sql.files }}"
      register: mysql_query
```

It throwing me following error

> failed: [13.82.109.51] (item={u'isdir': False, u'extension': u'.sql',
>   u'isreadonly': False, u'checksum':
>   u'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709', u'size': 0,
>   u'creationtime': 1500861234.9365487, u'filename': u'abcd.sql',
>   u'lastaccesstime': 1500861234.9365487, u'owner':
>   u'BUILTIN\Administrators', u'lastwritetime': 1500861234.9365487,
>   u'islnk': False, u'attributes': u'Archive', u'path':
>   u'C:\Users\atul\Documents\mysql-dev\17-06-2017\abcd.sql',
>   u'isarchive': True, u'ishidden': False, u'isshared': False}) =>
>   {"failed": true, "item": {"attributes": "Archive", "checksum":
>   "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709", "creationtime":
>   1500861234.9365487, "extension": ".sql", "filename": "abcd.sql", "isarchive": true, "isdir": false, "ishidden": false, "islnk": false,
>   "isreadonly": false, "isshared": false, "lastaccesstime":
>   1500861234.9365487, "lastwritetime": 1500861234.9365487, "owner": "BUILTIN\Administrators", "path":
>   "C:\Users\atul\Documents\mysql-dev\17-06-2017\abcd.sql", "size":
>   0}, "module_stderr": "At line:11 char:23\r\n+ except (AttributeError,
>   OSError):\r\n+                       ~\r\nMissing argument in
>   parameter list.\r\n\r\nAt line:13 char:3\r\n+ if scriptdir is not
>   None:\r\n+   ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r\n\r\nAt
>   line:20 char:3\r\n+ if sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+   ~\r\nMissing
>   '(' after 'if' in if statement.\r\n\r\nAt line:20 char:26\r\n+ if
>   sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                          ~\r\nMissing
>   expression after ','.\r\n\r\nAt line:20 char:21\r\n+ if
>   sys.version_info < (3,):\r\n+                     ~\r\nThe '<'
>   operator is reserved for future use.\r\n\r\nAt line:27 char:5\r\n+
>   from io import BytesIO as IOStream\r\n+     ~~~~\r\nThe 'from' keyword
>   is not supported in this version of the language.\r\n\r\nAt line:29
>   char:5\r\n+     from StringIO import StringIO as IOStream\r\n+
>   ~~~~\r\nThe 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the
>   language.\r\n\r\nAt line:31 char:25\r\n+ def invoke_module(module,
>   modlib_path, json_params):\r\n+                         ~\r\nMissing
>   argument in parameter list.\r\n\r\nAt line:33 char:7\r\n+     if
>   pythonpath:\r\n+       ~\r\nMissing '(' after 'if' in if
>   statement.\r\n\r\nAt line:34 char:57\r\n+
>   os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] = ':'.join((modlib_path, pythonpath))\r\n+
>   ~\r\nMissing argument in parameter list.\r\n\r\nNot all parse errors
>   were reported.  Correct the reported errors and try again.\r\n\r\n\r\n
>   + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordEx \r\n   ception\r\n    +
>   FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument\r\n \r\n\r\n",
>   "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}

I have also try by running mysql on command prompt but that is also throwing me following error

> failed: [13.82.109.51] (item={u'isdir': False, u'extension': u'.sql',
>   u'isreadonly': False, u'checksum':
>   u'da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709', u'size': 0,
>   u'creationtime': 1500861234.9365487, u'filename': u'abcd.sql',
>   u'lastaccesstime': 1500861234.9365487, u'owner':
>   u'BUILTIN\Administrators', u'lastwritetime': 1500861234.9365487,
>   u'islnk': False, u'attributes': u'Archive', u'path':
>   u'C:\Users\atul\Documents\mysql-dev\17-06-2017\abcd.sql',
>   u'isarchive': True, u'ishidden': False, u'isshared': False}) =>
>   {"changed": true, "cmd": "mysql -uroot -p devdb <
>   C:\Users\atul\Documents\mysql-dev\17-06-2017\abcd.sql", "delta":
>   "0:00:00.031259", "end": "2017-07-24 06:35:33.243269", "failed": true,
>   "item": {"attributes": "Archive", "checksum":
>   "da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709", "creationtime":
>   1500861234.9365487, "extension": ".sql", "filename": "abcd.sql", "isarchive": true, "isdir": false, "ishidden": false, "islnk": false,
>   "isreadonly": false, "isshared": false, "lastaccesstime":
>   1500861234.9365487, "lastwritetime": 1500861234.9365487, "owner": "BUILTIN\Administrators", "path":
>   "C:\Users\atul\Documents\mysql-dev\17-06-2017\abcd.sql", "size":
>   0}, "rc": 1, "start": "2017-07-24 06:35:33.212010", "stderr": "",
>   "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for
>   Win64 (x86_64)\r\nCopyright (c) 2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its
>   affiliates. All rights reserved.\r\n\r\nOracle is a registered
>   trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its\r\naffiliates. Other names
>   may be trademarks of their respective\r\nowners.\r\n\r\nUsage: mysql
>   [OPTIONS] [database]\r\n  -?, --help          Display this help and
>   exit.\r\n  -I, --help          Synonym for -?\r\n  --auto-rehash
>   Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to use\r\n
>   'rehash' to get table and field completion, but startup\r\n
>   and reconnecting may take a longer time. Disable with\r\n
>   --disable-auto-rehash.\r\n                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)\r\n  -A, --no-auto-rehash \r\n                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get\r\n
>   table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of\r\n
>   mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.\r\n  --auto-vertical-output
>   \r\n                      Automatically switch to vertical output mode
>   if the\r\n                      result is wider than the terminal
>   width.\r\n  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable
>   interactive behavior.\r\n                      (Enables --silent.)\r\n
>   --bind-address=name IP address to bind to.\r\n  -b, --binary-as-hex Print binary data as hex\r\n  --character-sets-dir=name \r\n
>   Directory for character set files.\r\n  --column-type-info  Display
>   column type information.\r\n  -c, --comments      Preserve comments.
>   Send comments to the server. The\r\n                      default is
>   --skip-comments (discard comments), enable\r\n                      with --comments.\r\n  -C, --compress      Use compression in
>   server/client protocol.\r\n  -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug
>   version. Catch this and exit.\r\n  --debug-check       This is a
>   non-debug version. Catch this and exit.\r\n  -T, --debug-info    This
>   is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.\r\n  -D, --database=name
>   Database to use.\r\n  --default-character-set=name \r\n
>   Set the default character set.\r\n  --delimiter=name    Delimiter to
>   be used.\r\n  --enable-cleartext-plugin \r\n
>   Enable/disable the clear text authentication plugin.\r\n  -e,
>   --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history\r\n                      file.)\r\n  -E, --vertical      Print
>   the output of a query (rows) vertically.\r\n  -f, --force
>   Continue even if we get an SQL error.\r\n  --histignore=name   A
>   colon-separated list of patterns to keep statements\r\n
>   from getting logged into syslog and mysql history.\r\n  -G,
>   --named-commands \r\n                      Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's\r\n                      internal
>   commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the\r\n
>   named commands can be used from any line of the query,\r\n
>   otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.\r\n
>   Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is\r\n
>   disabled by default.\r\n  -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after
>   function names.\r\n  --init-command=name SQL Command to execute when
>   connecting to MySQL server.\r\n                      Will
>   automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.\r\n  --local-infile
>   Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.\r\n  -b, --no-beep       Turn
>   off beep on error.\r\n  -h, --host=name     Connect to host.\r\n  -H,
>   --html          Produce HTML output.\r\n  -X, --xml           Produce XML output.\r\n  --line-numbers      Write line numbers for
>   errors.\r\n                      (Defaults to on; use
>   --skip-line-numbers to disable.)\r\n  -L, --skip-line-numbers \r\n                      Don't write line number for errors.\r\n  -n, --unbuffered    Flush
>   buffer after each query.\r\n  --column-names      Write column names
>   in results.\r\n                      (Defaults to on; use
>   --skip-column-names to disable.)\r\n  -N, --skip-column-names \r\n                      Don't write column names in results.\r\n  --sigint-ignore     Ignore
>   SIGINT (CTRL-C).\r\n  -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except
>   those that occur while the\r\n                      default database
>   is the one named at the command line.\r\n  -p, --password[=name] \r\n 
>   Password to use when connecting to server. If password is\r\n
>   not given it's asked from the tty.\r\n  -W, --pipe          Use named
>   pipes to connect to server.\r\n  -P, --port=#        Port number to
>   use for connection or 0 for default to, in\r\n
>   order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,\r\n
>   /etc/services, built-in default (3306).\r\n  --prompt=name       Set
>   the mysql prompt to this value.\r\n  --protocol=name     The protocol
>   to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,\r\n
>   memory).\r\n  -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by
>   row. This may slow\r\n                      down the server if the
>   output is suspended. Doesn't use\r\n                      history
>   file.\r\n  -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used
>   with --batch.\r\n  --reconnect         Reconnect if the connection is
>   lost. Disable with\r\n                      --disable-reconnect. This
>   option is enabled by default.\r\n                      (Defaults to
>   on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)\r\n  -s, --silent        Be more
>   silent. Print results with a tab as separator,\r\n
>   each row on new line.\r\n  --shared-memory-base-name=name \r\n
>   Base name of shared memory.\r\n  -S, --socket=name   The socket file
>   to use for connection.\r\n  --ssl-mode=name     SSL connection
>   mode.\r\n  --ssl               Deprecated. Use --ssl-mode instead.\r\n
>   (Defaults to on; use --skip-ssl to disable.)\r\n 
>   --ssl-verify-server-cert \r\n                      Deprecated. Use --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY instead.\r\n  --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format.\r\n  --ssl-capath=name   CA directory.\r\n 
>   --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format.\r\n  --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use.\r\n  --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM
>   format.\r\n  --ssl-crl=name      Certificate revocation list.\r\n 
>   --ssl-crlpath=name  Certificate revocation list path.\r\n  --tls-version=name  TLS version to use, permitted values are: TLSv1, TLSv1.1\r\n  -t, --table         Output in table format.\r\n 
>   --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See interactive help (\h)\r\n                      also. Does not work in batch mode.
>   Disable with\r\n                      --disable-tee. This option is
>   disabled by default.\r\n  -u, --user=name     User for login if not
>   current user.\r\n  -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE
>   that uses keys.\r\n  -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option
>   --safe-updates, -U.\r\n  -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).\r\n  -V, --version       Output
>   version information and exit.\r\n  -w, --wait          Wait and retry
>   if connection is down.\r\n  --connect-timeout=# Number of seconds
>   before connection timeout.\r\n  --max-allowed-packet=# \r\n
>   The maximum packet length to send to or receive from\r\n
>   server.\r\n  --net-buffer-length=# \r\n                      The
>   buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.\r\n  --select-limit=#
>   Automatic limit for SELECT when using --safe-updates.\r\n 
>   --max-join-size=#   Automatic limit for rows in a join when using\r\n                      --safe-updates.\r\n  --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old\r\n                      (pre-4.1.1) protocol.
>   Deprecated. Always TRUE\r\n  --server-arg=name   Send embedded server
>   this as a parameter.\r\n  --show-warnings     Show warnings after
>   every statement.\r\n  -j, --syslog        Log filtered interactive
>   commands to syslog. Filtering of\r\n                      commands
>   depends on the patterns supplied via histignore\r\n
>   option besides the default patterns.\r\n  --plugin-dir=name
>   Directory for client-side plugins.\r\n  --default-auth=name Default
>   authentication client-side plugin to use.\r\n  --binary-mode       By
>   default, ASCII '\0' is disallowed and '\r\n' is\r\n
>   translated to '\n'. This switch turns off both features,\r\n
>   and also turns off parsing of all clientcommands except\r\n
>   \C and DELIMITER, in non-interactive mode (for input\r\n
>   piped to mysql or loaded using the 'source' command).\r\n
>   This is necessary when processing output from mysqlbinlog\r\n
>   that may contain blobs.\r\n  --connect-expired-password \r\n
>   Notify the server that this client is prepared to handle\r\n
>   expired password sandbox mode.\r\n\r\nDefault options are read from
>   the following files in the given order:\r\nC:\Windows\my.ini
>   C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf C:\Program
>   Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL
>   Server 5.7\my.cnf C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.7\bin\my.ini C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\my.cnf \r\nThe following groups are read: mysql client\r\nThe following options may be given as the first
>   argument:\r\n--print-defaults        Print the program argument list
>   and exit.\r\n--no-defaults           Don't read default options from
>   any option file,\r\n                        except for login
>   file.\r\n--defaults-file=#       Only read default options from the
>   given file #.\r\n--defaults-extra-file=# Read this file after the
>   global files are read.\r\n--defaults-group-suffix=#\r\n
>   Also read groups with concat(group, suffix)\r\n--login-path=#
>   Read this path from the login file.\r\n\r\nVariables
>   (--variable-name=value)\r\nand boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value
>   (after reading options)\r\n---------------------------------
>   ----------------------------------------\r\nauto-rehash                       TRUE\r\nauto-vertical-output              FALSE\r\nbind-address
>   (No default value)\r\nbinary-as-hex
>   FALSE\r\ncharacter-sets-dir                (No default
>   value)\r\ncolumn-type-info                  FALSE\r\ncomments
>   FALSE\r\ncompress                          FALSE\r\ndatabase
>   (No default value)\r\ndefault-character-set
>   auto\r\ndelimiter                         ;\r\nenable-cleartext-plugin
>   FALSE\r\nvertical                          FALSE\r\nforce
>   FALSE\r\nhistignore                        (No default
>   value)\r\nnamed-commands                    FALSE\r\nignore-spaces
>   FALSE\r\ninit-command                      (No default
>   value)\r\nlocal-infile                      FALSE\r\nno-beep
>   FALSE\r\nhost                              (No default value)\r\nhtml 
>   FALSE\r\nxml                               FALSE\r\nline-numbers
>   TRUE\r\nunbuffered                        FALSE\r\ncolumn-names
>   TRUE\r\nsigint-ignore                     FALSE\r\nport
>   0\r\nprompt                            mysql> \r\nquick
>   FALSE\r\nraw                               FALSE\r\nreconnect
>   FALSE\r\nshared-memory-base-name           (No default
>   value)\r\nsocket                            (No default value)\r\nssl 
>   TRUE\r\nssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE\r\nssl-ca
>   (No default value)\r\nssl-capath                        (No default
>   value)\r\nssl-cert                          (No default
>   value)\r\nssl-cipher                        (No default
>   value)\r\nssl-key                           (No default
>   value)\r\nssl-crl                           (No default
>   value)\r\nssl-crlpath                       (No default
>   value)\r\ntls-version                       (No default
>   value)\r\ntable                             FALSE\r\nuser
>   root\r\nsafe-updates                      FALSE\r\ni-am-a-dummy
>   FALSE\r\nconnect-timeout                   0\r\nmax-allowed-packet
>   16777216\r\nnet-buffer-length                 16384\r\nselect-limit
>   1000\r\nmax-join-size                     1000000\r\nsecure-auth
>   TRUE\r\nshow-warnings                     FALSE\r\nplugin-dir
>   (No default value)\r\ndefault-auth                      (No default
>   value)\r\nbinary-mode
>   FALSE\r\nconnect-expired-password          FALSE\r\n", "stdout_lines":
>   ["mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.19, for Win64 (x86_64)", "Copyright (c)
>   2000, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.", "",
>   "Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its",
>   "affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective",
>   "owners.", "", "Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]", "  -?, --help
>   Display this help and exit.", "  -I, --help          Synonym for -?",
>   "  --auto-rehash       Enable automatic rehashing. One doesn't need to
>   use", "                      'rehash' to get table and field
>   completion, but startup", "                      and reconnecting may
>   take a longer time. Disable with", "
>   --disable-auto-rehash.", "                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-auto-rehash to disable.)", "  -A, --no-auto-rehash ", "                      No automatic rehashing. One has to use 'rehash' to get", "
>   table and field completion. This gives a quicker start of", "
>   mysql and disables rehashing on reconnect.", "  --auto-vertical-output
>   ", "                      Automatically switch to vertical output mode
>   if the", "                      result is wider than the terminal
>   width.", "  -B, --batch         Don't use history file. Disable
>   interactive behavior.", "                      (Enables --silent.)", "
>   --bind-address=name IP address to bind to.", "  -b, --binary-as-hex Print binary data as hex", "  --character-sets-dir=name ", "
>   Directory for character set files.", "  --column-type-info  Display
>   column type information.", "  -c, --comments      Preserve comments.
>   Send comments to the server. The", "                      default is
>   --skip-comments (discard comments), enable", "                      with --comments.", "  -C, --compress      Use compression in
>   server/client protocol.", "  -#, --debug[=#]     This is a non-debug
>   version. Catch this and exit.", "  --debug-check       This is a
>   non-debug version. Catch this and exit.", "  -T, --debug-info    This
>   is a non-debug version. Catch this and exit.", "  -D, --database=name
>   Database to use.", "  --default-character-set=name ", "
>   Set the default character set.", "  --delimiter=name    Delimiter to
>   be used.", "  --enable-cleartext-plugin ", "
>   Enable/disable the clear text authentication plugin.", "  -e,
>   --execute=name  Execute command and quit. (Disables --force and history", "                      file.)", "  -E, --vertical      Print
>   the output of a query (rows) vertically.", "  -f, --force
>   Continue even if we get an SQL error.", "  --histignore=name   A
>   colon-separated list of patterns to keep statements", "
>   from getting logged into syslog and mysql history.", "  -G,
>   --named-commands ", "                      Enable named commands. Named commands mean this program's", "                      internal
>   commands; see mysql> help . When enabled, the", "
>   named commands can be used from any line of the query,", "
>   otherwise only from the first line, before an enter.", "
>   Disable with --disable-named-commands. This option is", "
>   disabled by default.", "  -i, --ignore-spaces Ignore space after
>   function names.", "  --init-command=name SQL Command to execute when
>   connecting to MySQL server.", "                      Will
>   automatically be re-executed when reconnecting.", "  --local-infile
>   Enable/disable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.", "  -b, --no-beep       Turn
>   off beep on error.", "  -h, --host=name     Connect to host.", "  -H,
>   --html          Produce HTML output.", "  -X, --xml           Produce XML output.", "  --line-numbers      Write line numbers for errors.",
>   "                      (Defaults to on; use --skip-line-numbers to
>   disable.)", "  -L, --skip-line-numbers ", "                      Don't
>   write line number for errors.", "  -n, --unbuffered    Flush buffer
>   after each query.", "  --column-names      Write column names in
>   results.", "                      (Defaults to on; use
>   --skip-column-names to disable.)", "  -N, --skip-column-names ", "                      Don't write column names in results.", "  --sigint-ignore     Ignore
>   SIGINT (CTRL-C).", "  -o, --one-database  Ignore statements except
>   those that occur while the", "                      default database
>   is the one named at the command line.", "  -p, --password[=name] ", " 
>   Password to use when connecting to server. If password is", "
>   not given it's asked from the tty.", "  -W, --pipe          Use named
>   pipes to connect to server.", "  -P, --port=#        Port number to
>   use for connection or 0 for default to, in", "
>   order of preference, my.cnf, $MYSQL_TCP_PORT,", "
>   /etc/services, built-in default (3306).", "  --prompt=name       Set
>   the mysql prompt to this value.", "  --protocol=name     The protocol
>   to use for connection (tcp, socket, pipe,", "
>   memory).", "  -q, --quick         Don't cache result, print it row by
>   row. This may slow", "                      down the server if the
>   output is suspended. Doesn't use", "                      history
>   file.", "  -r, --raw           Write fields without conversion. Used
>   with --batch.", "  --reconnect         Reconnect if the connection is
>   lost. Disable with", "                      --disable-reconnect. This
>   option is enabled by default.", "                      (Defaults to
>   on; use --skip-reconnect to disable.)", "  -s, --silent        Be more
>   silent. Print results with a tab as separator,", "
>   each row on new line.", "  --shared-memory-base-name=name ", "
>   Base name of shared memory.", "  -S, --socket=name   The socket file
>   to use for connection.", "  --ssl-mode=name     SSL connection mode.",
>   "  --ssl               Deprecated. Use --ssl-mode instead.", "
>   (Defaults to on; use --skip-ssl to disable.)", " 
>   --ssl-verify-server-cert ", "                      Deprecated. Use --ssl-mode=VERIFY_IDENTITY instead.", "  --ssl-ca=name       CA file in PEM format.", "  --ssl-capath=name   CA directory.", " 
>   --ssl-cert=name     X509 cert in PEM format.", "  --ssl-cipher=name   SSL cipher to use.", "  --ssl-key=name      X509 key in PEM format.",
>   "  --ssl-crl=name      Certificate revocation list.", " 
>   --ssl-crlpath=name  Certificate revocation list path.", "  --tls-version=name  TLS version to use, permitted values are: TLSv1, TLSv1.1", "  -t, --table         Output in table format.", " 
>   --tee=name          Append everything into outfile. See interactive help (\h)", "                      also. Does not work in batch mode.
>   Disable with", "                      --disable-tee. This option is
>   disabled by default.", "  -u, --user=name     User for login if not
>   current user.", "  -U, --safe-updates  Only allow UPDATE and DELETE
>   that uses keys.", "  -U, --i-am-a-dummy  Synonym for option
>   --safe-updates, -U.", "  -v, --verbose       Write more. (-v -v -v gives the table output format).", "  -V, --version       Output
>   version information and exit.", "  -w, --wait          Wait and retry
>   if connection is down.", "  --connect-timeout=# Number of seconds
>   before connection timeout.", "  --max-allowed-packet=# ", "
>   The maximum packet length to send to or receive from", "
>   server.", "  --net-buffer-length=# ", "                      The
>   buffer size for TCP/IP and socket communication.", "  --select-limit=#
>   Automatic limit for SELECT when using --safe-updates.", " 
>   --max-join-size=#   Automatic limit for rows in a join when using", "                      --safe-updates.", "  --secure-auth       Refuse client connecting to server if it uses old", "                      (pre-4.1.1) protocol.
>   Deprecated. Always TRUE", "  --server-arg=name   Send embedded server
>   this as a parameter.", "  --show-warnings     Show warnings after
>   every statement.", "  -j, --syslog        Log filtered interactive
>   commands to syslog. Filtering of", "                      commands
>   depends on the patterns supplied via histignore", "
>   option besides the default patterns.", "  --plugin-dir=name
>   Directory for client-side plugins.", "  --default-auth=name Default
>   authentication client-side plugin to use.", "  --binary-mode       By
>   default, ASCII '\0' is disallowed and '\r\n' is", "
>   translated to '\n'. This switch turns off both features,", "
>   and also turns off parsing of all clientcommands except", "
>   \C and DELIMITER, in non-interactive mode (for input", "

I am not sure why this happening because everything working fine in Linux instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure why this happening because everything working fine in Linux instance.

[`mysql_db` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/mssql_db_module.html) does not work on Windows Server target, because it's a regular Python module intended for use on Unix/Linux machines. So you should execute it on a machine that meets the requirements:

> Requirements (on host that executes module)
>
> - `python` >= 2.7
> - `pymssql`

There is no need to run it on a machine running MySQL server itself, you can just point to the Windows server in `login_host` parameter and run the action on Ansible control machine using `delegate_to` or `local_action`.

---

[`win_command` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/win_command_module.html) does not work, because you use shell redirection (`< {{ item.path }}`):

> The given command will be executed on all selected nodes. It will not be processed through the shell, so variables like `$env:HOME` and operations like `<`, `>`, `|`, and `;` will not work (use the `win_shell` module if you need these features).

Answer (score 0):

Actually i got my query working by using following command

```
win_shell: "cmd /c --% mysql -h localhost -u{{ db_user }} -p{{ db_pass }}   {{ db_database }} < {{ item.path }}"
```

Thanks to this link
[powershell The '<' operator is reserved for future use in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503642/powershell-the-operator-is-reserved-for-future-use-in-java)