# PSQL COPY can't find file

Tags: postgresql, filepath, psql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to execute this command:

`PS C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin> .\psql.exe -h front.linux-pgsql01.qa.local -p 5432 -d site -U qa -w  -c "Delete from product_factor_lolek; COPY product_factor_lolek FROM E'C:\\OP_data\\SEARCH\\1.csv' delimiter '^' CSV;"`

My file is located on this path: C:\OP_data\SEARCH\1.csv. But in fact, I've got an error:

`ERROR:  could not open file "C:\OP_data\SEARCH\1.csv" for reading: No such file or directory`

I am using Windows server, PostgreSQL 9.4. What should I write for correct path?

P.S. I can't use \COPY

Answer (score 1):

The `COPY` command will attempt to access your CSV file on Server (`front.linux-pgsql01.qa.local`), not in the client. So you must send your CSV to there and point the command to its path or use `stdin` as you mentioned:

```
psql.exe -h front.linux-pgsql01.qa.local -p 5432 -d site -U qa -w -c "Delete from product_factor_lolek; COPY product_factor_lolek FROM STDIN' delimiter '^' CSV;" < C:\OP_data\SEARCH\1.csv
```

Comment: Ok, but what if I want to use .csv file on my local machine? Should I use "STDIN" for this one? And if Yes, how can I do this?

Comment: @AntonErjomin Yes, it's possible. See my edited answer.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I still have an error message: 
`PS C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin> .\psql.exe -h front.linux-pgsql01.qa.local -p 5432 -d site -U qa -w  -c "Delete
from product_factor_lolek; COPY product_factor_lolek FROM STDIN delimiter '^' CSV;" < C:\\OP_data\\SEARCH\\1.csv
At line:1 char:165
+ ... iter '^' CSV;" < C:\\OP_data\\SEARCH\\1.csv
+                    ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported`

Comment: @AntonErjomin What's your Windows Server version?

Comment: @AntonErjomin Please see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2148816/7925366) to do a workaround on this problem. It's related with your Windows Version.