# how to install sass in virtual environment

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install `sass` in a project which is a project of a `virtual environment`. I am very new to `python` or `virtual env`.

so I was going through this [article](https://pyscss.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html) and following steps.

I did the following first step and now I can see `pyScss` inside `Lib` folder which is inside `venv` folder

```
pip install pyScss
```

now the following steps not working.

```
python -m scss < reporting/assets/style.scss
```

it throws this error

```
At line:1 char:16
+ python -m scss < reporting/assets/style.scss
+                ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported
```

from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148746/the-operator-is-reserved-for-future-use) I tried replacing `<` with `|` which also throws other error.

I am quite not understanding what should I do here. even this seems to the problem related with the operating system or anything, my goal is to understand `sass` implementation in the `virtual-env` project.

I would appreciate anyone helps me to fix the issue or showing me any other guidence.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you on Windows? Are you using PowerShell or cmd?

Comment: @Peilonrayz yes I am with powershell in widows.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Python. Please tag this with powershell.

Comment: Escape `<` with ``"`"``. `<` is a special character reserved for `STDIN` therefore when `STDIN` is not being used you will get that error. Try ```python -m scss `< reporting/assets/style.scss``` or `reporting/assets/style.scss | python -m scss`

Comment: @Neko Musume thank you. it worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `<` with `` "`" ``. `<` is a special character reserved for `STDIN` therefore when `STDIN` is not being used you will get that error. Try

```
python -m scss `< reporting/assets/style.scss
```

or

```
reporting/assets/style.scss | python -m scss
```