# Missing file specification after redirection operator

Tags: powershell, heredoc, herestring

I got the following error:

```
| cat << EOF > config.yaml 
|      ~ 
Missing file specification after redirection operator.`
```

my code in power shell is following

```
cat << EOF > config.yaml
serve:
  proxy:
    port: 4455 # run the proxy at port 4455
...
EOF
```

I am running in windows server

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell's error message is somewhat confusing here, given that it doesn't support `<` at all (only `>`). However, the _parser_ knows about `<` and with a _syntactically correct_ use of `<` would reveal the non-support; e.g. `cat < foo` would result in error `The '<' operator is reserved for future use.`  It is unlikely that it will ever be supported, however. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2148746/45375) for what to use instead of `<`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mistakenly trying to use **`bash`** syntax *in PowerShell*, namely a **[*here-document*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Documents)**.

The **PowerShell equivalent**, with different syntax, is a **[*here-string*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings)**.<sup>[1]</sup>

The equivalent of the `bash` statement in your question in PowerShell is:

```
# PowerShell
@"
serve:
  proxy:
    port: 4455 # run the proxy at port 4455
...
"@ > config.yaml
```

Note:

- Use `@'` / `'@` instead as the delimiters to treat the content *verbatim*, i.e. to *suppress [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings)*, so that `$`-prefixed tokens aren't interpreted as variable references, for instance. This is the equivalent of quoting (any part of) the `EOF` delimiter in `bash` (e.g. `cat << 'EOF' ...`)
- Nothing may follow the opening delimiter (`@"`/ `@'`) on the same line, and the closing delimiter (`"@`/ `'@`) must be at the *very start* of the line - not even whitespace may precede it.
- PowerShell here-strings have *no* equivalent to the Bash here-document feature of stripping tab-based indentation from the content if the delimiter is prefixed with `-` (e.g. `cat << -EOF`).

***Windows PowerShell* caveats re *character encoding***:

- `>`, the effective alias of [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file), defaults to "Unicode" (UTF-16LE) in Windows PowerShell (by contrast, in *PowerShell (Core)* (v6+) the consistent default, across all cmdlets, is BOM-less UTF-8).
- To control the character encoding, call `Out-File` - or, with text input, preferably - [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) with the `-Encoding` parameter.

  - E.g., replace `> config.yaml` with `| Set-Content -Encoding Ascii config.yaml`
  - However, note that if you need UTF-8 encoding, `-Encoding utf8` will invariably create a file *with a BOM* in Windows PowerShell (but not in PowerShell (Core), as noted); to avoid that, direct use of .NET APIs is needed - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375).

---

<sup>[1] Not to be confused with *`bash`'s* [here-strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings), `<<<"..."`, which are a *single-line* alternative to here-documents.</sup>