# container to pipe to an executable and out again

Tags: docker, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I need a Docker image which contains a Linux executable where I can pipe an input file into when running it like this (in `cmd` on Windows or `bash` on Linux):

`docker run --rm -i myContainer < myInputFile > myOutputFile`

In my case it is the executable [cucumber-json-formatter-linux-386](https://github.com/cucumber/json-formatter/releases/) which converts NDJSON Cucumber messages into a JSON file (to be used e.g. for [Xray](https://www.getxray.app/)).

**Why Docker?**

- There is also a Windows executable available, but our security software says it contains a virus.
- So I can’t download it, but to be honest, I also don’t trust it.
- I need something OS indepedent, also running in CI, etc.

**Why convert?**

Cucumber can output JSON directly. But I am using [@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor) which only can output NDJSON and needs me to use that binary to convert it into JSON. [@badeball wrote](https://github.com/cucumber/common/pull/1916#issuecomment-1121228736) “I've refactored my implementation to output messages, because that was significantly easier implementation wise”. So it’s not Cucumber writing those NDJSON messages here.

Comment: If the project already publishes runnable binaries built for your architecture, do you actually need it in a Docker image?  It seems like directly running `./cucumber-json-formatter-linux-amd64` (maybe renaming the executable to be shorter) would be more convenient than trying to invoke `docker run` to do the same thing.

Comment: I just added some of the reasons. Hopefully it will be clear now. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you already have installed Docker, create a folder containing the following file called “Dockerfile”:

```
FROM scratch
COPY cucumber-json-formatter-linux-386 /formatter
ENTRYPOINT ["/formatter"]
```

Also copy the Linux executable ([cucumber-json-formatter-linux-386](https://github.com/cucumber/json-formatter/releases/)) into the same folder.

Then cd into that folder and build the container like this:

```
docker build -t cucumber-json-formatter .
```

Now you can run the container like this:

```
docker run --rm -i cucumber-json-formatter < input.ndjson > output.json
```

- The argument `--rm` removes the container after usage. Do this if you don't want a pile of dead containers to build up over time.
- The argument `-i` is needed to keep the input stream open, while the file is piped in.

I tried this on a Windows host (cmd, [not Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148746/the-operator-is-reserved-for-future-use)), but should work the same on Linux.

If you want to use it automatically in [@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor) add a file `.cypress-cucumber-preprocessorrc.json` on your project root, containing:

```
{
    "json": {
        "enabled": true,
        "formatter": "docker",
        "args": ["run", "--rm", "-i", "cucumber-json-formatter"]
    }
}
```

On test execution this will create a file `cucumber-messages.ndjson` and then `cucumber-report.json`, both on the project root.