# '<' operator is reserved PowerShell Error

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am trying to use `mysql -u root -p Tutorials < tut_backup.sql` in PowerShell to restore a table in a MySQL DB but it's giving me  `The '<' operator is reserved for future use.` error. Is there a roundabout way?

Answer (score 63):

How about

```
& cmd.exe /c "mysql -u root -p Tutorials < tut_backup.sql"
```

Answer (score 22):

You can pipe in the contents like so:

```
Get-Content tut_backup.sql | mysql -u root -p Tutorials
```

Comment: This saved me. Just dropping a comment because this answer helped me multiple times.

Comment: Works, at least for smaller files. But reads the entire file into memory, making larger files a no go (Program 'mysql.exe' failed to run: The capacity was less than the current size)

Answer (score 10):

Try this instead:

```
mysql -u root -p
(prompts for password)
source tut_backup.sql
```

- [`mysql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html) is the MySQL Command-Line Client
- `-u root` is the MySQL user name to use when connecting to server
- `-p` is the password to use when connecting to server. It's recommended to leave blank, and enter after the MySQL prompts for password, so your password doesn't leak to the PowerShell history file.
- for more options, such as a custom port, see [mysql Client Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html) in the official documentation.
- `source` is a command to execute an SQL script file. It takes a file name as an argument.
- for more commands, such as *"How do I exit <s>Vim</s> MySQL?"*, visit [mysql Client Commands](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html) page in the official documentation.

---

<sup>Credit for the idea to use mysql cli with `source` command goes to [wallyk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1774262/1429387).</sup>