# The '<' operator is reserved for future use command powershell

Tags: powershell, command, ros2

I'm trying to install ROS 2 in my computer and I need to run the following command:

```
choco install -y -s <PATH\TO\DOWNLOADS\> asio cunit eigen tinyxml-usestl tinyxml2 log4cxx
```

However the message I get when I run it is this:

- choco
- ~
  The operator '<' is reserved for future use

  - CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported

Anyone know how to solve it? I'm pretty lost so I'm just following the instructions they gave me, but I'm stuck here.

Comment: You need to replace the substring `<PATH\TO\DOWNLOADS>` with _the actual path to the intended downloads folder_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['<' operator is reserved PowerShell Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776495/operator-is-reserved-powershell-error)

Comment: I replaced the substring as you said but when running it I get this error:

Comment: @PedroLeal . . . you should edit your question to include the additional information you posted as an answer i.e. the screenshots

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `<PATH\TO\DOWNLOADS\>` with the actual path and use quotes when the path contains spaces:

`choco install -y -s 'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\ROS 2' asio cunit eigen tinyxml-usestl tinyxml2 log4cxx`